# jQuery Lightbox Help

Tags: jquery

Ok, I am a COMPLETE beginner, but in order to complete a website I am working on I need to create a lightbox that appears when clicked on a link.

The website I am creating is a portfolio of an artists work and I need to learn the jQuery that would mean that they can click on a photo and a div fades in with a larger version of that photo.

The smaller images are stored in a folder called "Portfolio" and the Lightbox image is stored in a folder called "lightbox".

The main problem I am having is not so much the lightbox but the image that shows up, how can I get the correct image to appear? Do I need an id in my div that corresponds to the jQuery?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The image that pops up is always the one that the thumbnail is linked to. In the following case, the *image.jpg* file from the *lightbox* folder will pop up when the thumbnail is clicked.

```
<a href="lightbox/image.jpg" rel="lightbox">
    <img src="portfolio/image-thumb.jpg" alt="..." />
</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks but how do I get it to fade in ie. whats the jQuery?

Comment: If you only need the lightbox functionality, you don't have to use jQuery. My code referred to a little nice plugin (which is apparently based on the Prototype framework), which is very easy to use and doesn't need any coding at all. See http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/.

Comment: Ok, but for my school assignment I need to create it by myself (although I need to confirm that, so I may just use this one for now).